# Unable to get color of pixels in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The canvas is divided in two parts. Left part is black and right part is white. I am using the following code to find white pixels in a specific line but it logs nothing to the console.

This is my code for turning the left half of the canvas black.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, cw/2, ch);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();
```

This is the code I am using to get pixel data:

```
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 300, 600, 2);
var pix = imgd.data;
var white_count = 0;
for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    var red = pix[i]; // red
    var green = pix[i+1]; // green
    var blue = pix[i+2]; // blue
    console.log(red);
    if(red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255) {
        white_count += 1;
    }
}
```

At least a few of the red values should have been 255 but they are all 0. Why is that happening? This is my JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/83Lb96vp/

Comment: any chance you could add the code where you create the canvas, so you have an easy to reproduce example of your problem so that it is easier to reproduce and find any possible problems (maybe it's not in your detection but which pixels you are getting)

Comment: @Icepickle I have attached a JSFiddle in the question and added some additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing the `getImageData` dimensions wrong.

It need to be [ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

take a look at this fiddle:

```js
console.clear();
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var sizeMod = 4; // one "sqare" is "sizeMod" * "sizeMod".
c.width = 10 * sizeMod;
c.height = 10 * sizeMod;
for (var x = 0; x < sizeMod; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < sizeMod; y++) {
    var color = (Math.abs(Math.round(1 + (Math.random() * 3)) * 4 - 1)).toString('16');
    color = '#' + color + color + color + color + color + color;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x * sizeMod, y * sizeMod, sizeMod, sizeMod);
  }
}
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 10 * sizeMod, 10 * sizeMod);
var pix = imgd.data;
var white_count = 0;
for (var p = 0; p < pix.length; p += 4) {
  var c = {
    r: pix[p + 0],
    g: pix[p + 1],
    b: pix[p + 2],
    a: pix[p + 3],
    hex: '#' + pix[p + 0].toString('16') + '' + pix[p + 1].toString('16') + '' + pix[p + 2].toString('16')
  }
  if (c.hex == '#ffffff') {
    white_count++;
  }
}
console.log(white_count + "\nis white\none tile is", (sizeMod * sizeMod), "big so", white_count / (sizeMod * sizeMod), "tiles")
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="10" height="10" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2ukj55o/3/)

Comment: Maybe I am creating the canvas in a wrong manner but I could not get it to work on my own fiddle. Could you please take a look? :)

https://jsfiddle.net/83Lb96vp/3/

Comment: @NeenaVivek i have updated you fiddle to measure a white band i'm inserting at the top. Take a look: [https://jsfiddle.net/83Lb96vp/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/83Lb96vp/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Emil I thought that the canvas will automatically detect the color set using CSS but I had to set the color using JavaScript. :)